# Background processes invoked from .bashrc (in tmux session) die when tmux exits?

Tags: bash, terminal, tmux

This is a doozy to explain, but here's the behavior I'm observing:

```
# ~/.bashrc

if [ -n "$TMUX" ]; then
  sleep 100 &
fi
```

With this in my `.bashrc`, I can launch a tmux session, `pgrep sleep`, and see one PID come up. I can detach from tmux and `pgrep sleep`, and it's still there.

But if I exit tmux entirely, then when I `pgrep sleep`, it's gone.

This is not the behavior I observe if I `sleep 100 &` manually in a new tmux session. It also doesn't happen when using `.bashrc` to invoke `sleep 100 &` in a bare terminal (*i.e.,* without tmux).

What gives? Is this expected behavior in tmux?

**EDIT:** This also applies to other startup scripts like `.bash_profile`. Or maybe it only applies to `.bash_profile` — I'm on a Mac, so I'm invoking `.bashrc` from `.bash_profile` anyway.